# Code analysis for dotnet core project in VS2017

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-core, code-analysis, visual-studio-2017

I want add code analysis (FxCop, not StyleCop) for my dotnet core project, it is targeting netcoreapp1.1 framework. 
I know that FxCop is built in MSBuild, but when I enabled it, I kept getting error:

*1>MSBUILD : error : CA0055 : Could not identify platform for 'C:\Dev\easycube\EasyCube.Authentication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\EasyCube.Authentication.dll'.
1>MSBUILD : error : CA0052 : No targets were selected.*

Then I found that there is Nuget package for dotnet core analyzer Microsoft.NetCore.Analyzers, but I do not know how to use it. Anyone know how to set it up on the project?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you running the analyzer? I am running into a similar issue if I run FxCop directly. I can't use a the analyze switch with dotnet build.

Comment: @illvm I installed package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers to my dotnet core project and add '<Features>IOperation</Features>' to the PropertyGroup in csproj file. The FxCop analysis will be run upon build the project

Comment: Maybe it's just a problem of the wrong version of analyzers. Take a look here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers#recommended-version-of-analyzer-packages

Answer (score 1):

.Net Core does not support Code Analysis the old way.

You need the Nuget Package [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers). Add it to your project and you will get the warnings. See [here for some more Analyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers).

If you try to run the old code analysis on a solution with .Net Core project you can switch it off for every project (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/758#issuecomment-407178295)) by adding a custom target to the end of the project files:

```
<Target Name="IgnoreRunCodeAnalysis" Condition=" '$(RunCodeAnalysis)' == 'true' " BeforeTargets="RunCodeAnalysis">
    <Message Importance="normal" Text="Set RunCodeAnalysisOnThisProject to false" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RunCodeAnalysisOnThisProject>false</RunCodeAnalysisOnThisProject>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```